# Symfony2 allowed memory exhausted when calling php app/console doctrine:schema:update

Tags: symfony

I have a big problem...

I want to update the schema of my database and I have a problem.

When I a running this script:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myApp/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php on line 509
```

I have tried to increase memory_limit in **php.ini** but nothing works.

I have ran the `php app/console cache:clear` but it does nothing. **Still the same problem**...

Please help...

I can't do nothing...

Comment: Probably you have another `php.ini` file for cli

Comment: thanks. php -d memory_limit=200M app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql works

Answer (score 31):

Do:

```
php -d memory_limit=200M app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

200M or higher

Comment: You're welcome :)
This method has the advantage to keep a reasonable value of memory_limit for others commands.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check php.ini location by creating php file that outputs php's configuration

```
<?php

    phpinfo();
```

Run this file in a browser and check "Loaded Configuration File" this is the location of php.ini.

Another method to solve the issue is to add the next line of code to app/console file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

64 MB should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate and Summarize of all answers and comments:

1. It does not matter what command you issue, what matters is your PHP configuration.
2. This is the error:

   > Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 434032 bytes)
3. Solution: in your php.ini change to this example, and restart Apache/web server:

   ```
   ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
   ; http://php.net/memory-limit
   memory_limit=512M
   ```

Tested and working.